# Allow only the author of the post to edit in class based views- Django?

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
class EditPost(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Posts
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name="posts/add_post.html"

    def test_func(self):
        x = self.request.user.pk
        print (x)
        y = Posts.objects.get(user='user')
        print (y)
        if x == y:
            return True
        else:
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                raise Http404("You are not allowed to edit this Post")
```

models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=1200, blank=False)
```

**How do i match the loggedin user and the user object of the Post**

i could not find any solution since i am using class based views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

add dispatch to EditPost class

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.get_object()
    if obj.user != self.request.user:
        raise Http404("You are not allowed to edit this Post")
    return super(EditPost, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing the check in `test_func` is tricky. You need to fetch the object once in `test_func` to check whether the user is allowed to use it, and then the object is fetched again by the same fiew.

An easier approach is to override the `get_queryset` method. If the user is not the author of the post, they will get a 404.

```
class EditPost(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(EditPost, self).filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the previous posts, try this:

Add to your class EditPost:

```
login_url = 'your url name or path to login page'
def test_func(self):
    obj = self.get_object()
    return obj.author == self.request.user
```

The `test_func` method is used by `UserPassesTestMixin` for this particular logic. To override it we set variable `obj` to the current object returned by the view using `get.object()`.
After that, if the author on the current object (`obj.author`) matches the current user (`self.request.user`) we allow editing. If not (i.e. `false`) we throw an error.

`login_url` is from `LoginRequiredMixin` and the default location is `/accounts/login`. To override it, set your own path or name of the login template. This will take those people who are not logged in to the login page.